# multi character constant, what am i doing wrong? C

Tags: c

```
if( ( !valInput(st1,0) ) || (st1[0] < '0') || (st1[0] > 'M-1') )
```

getting a warning: multi character constant
on the M char, and on the '0' ... why?

M is a defined variable replaced in compilation by the number 9\

```
 #define M 9
```

my usage is to check whether the first char is by chance smaller than '0' or greater than '8'
( for the 8 char, i am obliged to use the M defined )

any help we'll be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: `#define M 9` does not replace `M` in `'M-1'`

Comment: (st1[0] > 'M-1')  ===> **(st1[0] > (M-1+'0'))**

Comment: HAL
i guess you are right, but it works perfect this way and seem to DO replace it (multi-timed checked it)

@Gangadhar
Thank you, it worked great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `M` is quoted in your code, the preprocessor does not substitute it. (This rule applies to both single and quoted character strings).

Hence the compiler sees `'M-1'` which is a multi-character constant literal.

If you want to compare `st1[0]` to the ascii value of '8' then the easiest way is probably to use `M - 1 + '0'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(st1[0] > 'M-1')
```

shoud be

```
(st1[0] > M-1)
```

`'M-1'` itself is a multi-character constant, and will be evaluated to a integer.

Comment: but if i'll replace as suggested,
in run time the comparison will be the ascii value of st1[0], against integer value of 8 (which is 8).

it will cause troubles, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

If `M` is a pre-processor macro defined as `9` (and not the digit character `'9'`), and you are comparing characters, then you must convert to character before subtracting one:

```
if( ( !valInput(st1,0) ) || (st1[0] < '0') || (st1[0] > ('0' + M - 1) )
```

The `'0'` is added, together with the integer `9` (from `M`) that becomes the character `'9'`, from which 1 is then subtracted to get `'8'`.

Answer (score 0):

`'M-1'` is not what you expected. There `M` is not getting replaced by 8.

You can use `(st1[0] > (char)(M-1))`.